# VSCode JavaSript IntelliSense not showing suggestons for JavaScript string properties, methods and some mouse event properties

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, mouseevent, intellisense

My VSCode JS intellisense is working fine, but when dealing with JS string properties and methods and with some mouse event properties (like pageX, pageY) I do not get the desired intellisense.

I want this type of intelligence as shown in the brackets editor.

1. [image: brakets intellisensse for string property]
2. [image]
3. [image: List item]

Unfortunately, what I get in VSCode is this:

1. [image]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image]

So please suggest me a way to enable intellisense for js string properties , methods and also for some mouseevents.

(*I'm using VSCode Version: 1.50.1 (user setup)*)

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_javascript-language-support-in-html You won't get intellisense support for javascript in a script tag for things lke you are doing in the example code.

Comment: @mark ,bro i'm still not getting intellisense support for JS string properties and methods even after coding in a separate .js file. I think intellisense developers forgot to add intellisense support for JS string properties and methods and also for some mouse event properties